# Array to Return Year End Balances For The Past Five Years - (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to return only the year end information (December 31) for the past five years and display that information in a DataGrid. This does not include the current year.

My program is currently displaying month's end information from the previous year up to the last day of the most recent month in the current year (Example: The current month is May 2011 and the information being displayed in my DataGrid shows the data stored on Jan. 31, 2010; Feb. 28, 2010; Mar. 31, 2010....Dec. 31, 2010; Jan. 31, 2011; Feb. 28, 2011; Mar. 31, 2011; Apr. 30, 2011).

It also adds a totals row after Dec. 31, 2010 and another after Apr. 30, 2011. These two totals rows will not be needed in the new DataGrid.

Below is a snippet of the current code which is returning the months end information.

Please let me know if I left any information out or am not clear on my question.

I apologize in advance for such a rookie question, it has just been driving me crazy the past couple days that I cannot figure this out.

```
protected DataSet DS;
protected DataRow dr, dNew;

private void GetInfo()
{

}

private double getDbl(string columnName)
{
    if (dr[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
        return Double.Parse(dr[columnName].ToString());
    return 0;
}

private void Calculate()
{
    double cg, na, n, ka, nka, kaa, tca;
    double tmr, to, gpo;
    int year, rowcnt, rowindx, months;

    months = -1;
    rowindx = 0;
    cg = 0;
    na = 0;
    n = 0;
    ka = 0;
    nka = 0;
    kaa = 0;
    tca = 0;
    tmr = 0;
    tor = 0;
    gpo = 0;

    rowcnt = DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    if (rowcnt > 0) year = Int32.Parse(DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["cy"].ToString());
    else year = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowcnt; i++)
    {
        months++;
        dr = DS.Tables[0].Rows[i]

        if (year != Int32.Parse(dr["cy"].ToString())
        {
            dNew = DS.Tables[0].NewRow();
            dNew["ind"] = rowindx;
            dNew["cg"] = cg;
            dNew["na"] = na;
            dNew["n"] = n;
            dNew["ka"] = ka / months;
            dNew["nka"] = nka / months;
            dNew["kaa"] = kaa / months;
            dNew["tca"] = tca / months;
            dNew["tmr"] = tmr / months;
            dNew["tor"] = tor;
            dNew["gpo"] = gpo / months;

            cg = 0;
            na = 0;
            n = 0;
            ka = 0;
            nka = 0;
            kaa = 0;
            tca = 0;
            tmr = 0;
            tor = 0;
            gpo = 0;
            months = 1;
            year = Int32.Parse(dr["cy"].ToString());
            rowindx++;

            DS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dNew);

            dNew = DS.Tables[0].NewRow();
            dNew["ind"] = rowindx;
            rowindx++;
            DS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dNew);
        }

        cg += getDbl("cg");
        na += getDbl("na");
        n += getDbl("n");
        ka += getDbl("ka");
        nka += getDbl("nka");
        kaa += getDbl("kaa");
        tca += getDbl("tca");
        tmr += getDbl("tmr");
        tor += getDbl("tor");
        gpo += getDbl("gpo");
        dr["ind"] = rowindx;
        rowindx++;
    }

    dNew = DS.Tables[0].NewRow();
    dNew["ind"] = rowindx;
    dNew["cg"] = cg;
    dNew["na"] = na;
         dNew["n"] = naum;
         dNew["ka"] = ka / months;
         dNew["nka"] = nka / months;
         dNew["kaa"] = kaa / months;
         dNew["tca"] = tca / months;
         dNew["tmr"] = tmr / months;
         dNew["tor"] = tor;
         dNew["gpo"] = gpo / months;
         DS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dNew);

      DS.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "ind";
}
```

Comment: You have left out your question. What are you having problems with?

Comment: Where is this data coming from?  If it is coming from a database, I would recommend doing a query that calculates the data for you.

Comment: I would suggest you remove all the unnecessary stuff from your question to allow people to better understand your question. For example, I don't think all these "dNew["ka"] = ka / months; dNew["nka"] = nka / months; dNew["kaa"] = kaa / months;" should be there, they just unfocus people who what to help from the actual issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried limiting the dataset query to just the year the you want?

Comment: Yes, the data is coming from a database and I set the query to return the Parameter to show "DateTime.Now.Year - 5" which does bring back the data for the past 5 years. The only thing is that it is bring back the month's end data for the past 5 years. Instead of only having 5 rows (2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010) I am getting 50 rows.

Comment: I think you need to show the query then. Calculate is doing its work on all the rows, you either need to do it 1 year at a time (in the query), or change your loop so that it does the required maths.

Comment: You need to post the query because you should be getting 60 results not 50.

Comment: SELECT a.year, " +
"a.c_month , " +
"a.f_year , " +
"a.f_month , " +
"sum(cg) cg, " + 
"sum(na) na, " +
"sum(naa) naa, " +
"sum(ka) ka, " +
"sum(kaa) kaa, " +
"sum(tca) tca, " +
"sum(round(tmr, 6)) tmr, " +
"sum(tor) tor, " +
"sum(round(gpo, 6)) gpo, " +
"sum(cr) cr, " +
"sum(ab) ab, " +
"sum(nka) nka, " +
"sum(cna) cna, " +
"sum(tmg) tmg, " +
"sum(tmr) tmr, " +
"sum(decode(cn, null, 0, cn))cn, " +
"sum(decode(n, null, 0, n)) n " +
"FROM xxx a, yyy.brc b " +
"WHERE a.rn = b.ord(+) and " +
"(a.rn = :rn or b.nrn = :rn2) and " +
"cy >= :cy ";

Comment: I am then setting a variable to a new DataTable and adding the columns to that DataTable, calculating and binding the data to the DataGrid.

Comment: I get the feeling it should not be that difficult. Basically I would have thought either changing the query so that you use the year (so you would do 5 selects). Or changing the for loop to do a years worth at a time.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give me an example please? I am sorry for the trouble, arrays are just one of those areas I still have yet to get a firm grasp on.

Comment: Not sure I can do that with the code in its current state. Try to get down in pseudo code what you want to do. Probably start in your query, and change the last statement to be cy = :cy. Just concentrate on doing 1 years worth first.

Comment: I figured out the problem I was having. In my query I needed a second parameter which would account for the month. ..."WHERE a.rn = b.ord(+) and " + "(a.rn = :rn or b.nrn = :rn2) and " + "cy >= :cy " "cm = :cm ";" Adding a parameter for the month "cm = :cm " and setting the OracleParameter value = 12 solved my problem. Thank you all very much for the help, I really appreciate evreything!